# wkhtmltopdf not accepting values in url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wkhtmltopdf

So I'm creating a tool which uses wkhtmltopdf to convert my html to PDF.
for example this does work:

```
wkhtmltopdf google.com test1.pdf
```

However my tool requires to have some values changed whenever this is necessary, and that's why I send my values through my url.

I send these values like this:

```
.[url]final.php?myTextField1=name&myTextField2=man&myTextField3=Blablablabla&myTextField4=kleur&myTextField5=zekerwel&myTextField6=hoihallo
```

However if I try to convert this url like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf [url]/final.php?myTextField1=name&myTextField2=man&myTextField3=Blablablabla&myTextField4=kleur&myTextField5=zekerwel&myTextField6=hoihallo test1.pdf
```

wkhtmltopdf does not seem to accept it, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You do realise there is already PHP class that does this? https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: You did not really link me to anything useful..

Comment: It successfully converted every page I've thrown at it.

Comment: I meant that you did not link to any specific class, just to wkhtmltopdf's github page. I use it already as a command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I have used the tool, but there were a few issues I recall to using it this way -- one was you had to make sure to wrap the urls in quotes.

Comment: Could you show an example as my english isn't the best.. I don't understand really.

Comment: As an aside: I tried some github classes as mentioned elsewhere but none of them worked correctly and I ended up having to write my own which was spawned off in a separate thread which I monitored and killed if it ran over a set number of seconds.

Comment: I just mean: wkhtmltopdf "myurl.com?q=1&a=2" -- quotations like that. See if that solves the issue.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! Never thought that would be the fix as it does accept normal websites without quotes.